# open() "r+" option working incorrectly

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, io

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:46:21)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> c = open("/home/aditya/Documents/in.txt","r+")
>>> c.read()
'GNU and python are amazing.\n'
>>> c.write("Oh yes they are!")
>>> c.read()
''
>>> c.close()
>>>
aditya@aditya-Latitude-D620:~$
```

I learnt in my course that "r+" can b used for read and write. However, after I write() something, I'm unable to read it. The read() method returns a null value. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File has a position. Once you read, write, the position is advanced.

Unless you reposition the position, next operation occurred in current position.

You can rewind the file, using [`file.seek`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek). For example to rewind to the beginning of the file:

```
file_object.seek(0)
```

Comment: ,is there a way to seek() to a different line like hello world\nhello python. can i use the seek command to go the second line from the first line

Comment: @adch99, I don't understand what you mean. position (offset) should be numbers. (positive/negative)